# ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND unexpectedly returned for OpenBackupEventLog function

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke, marshalling

I'm trying to open an .evtx file on a Windows 7 x64 machine using the [OpenBackupEventLog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363671%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function however I keep on getting [ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (error code 2) even though the file **does** exist.

My P/Invoke declaration / point where I call the file is:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = false, EntryPoint = "OpenBackupEventLog")]
public static extern IntPtr OpenBackupEventLog(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]string uncServerName,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]string fileName);

IntPtr ptr = NativeMethods.OpenBackupEventLog(null, filename);
if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero && File.Exists(filename))
{
    // This exception is thrown and so the file does exist
    throw new Win32Exception(string.Format("Failed to open event log archive '{0}'", filename));
}
```

Note that this is inside an x86 process.

The only thing that I can think of is that the problem is down to Unicode / ANSI marshalling (previously I recall getting `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` instead), however I've double checked and playing around with the marshalling has no effect.

Why is this failing to open the file / how can I diagnose this?

Comment: Since you suspect the string marshalling, I'd suggest trying without those explicit attributes on the string arguments. As for diagnosing further: check if this method is logged by [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645); if so, it will show the exact name of the file you're accessing.

Comment: Oh, also _do_ try it in an x64 process to eliminate the possibility that the redirection layer is messing you up. Are these files in `%SYSTEMROOT%\system32`? (C:\Windows\system32) - then that's definitely a big suspect.

Comment: @romkyns The files are on my desktop

Comment: Can you show the code/path that you are using to access the files on your desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", ..., EntryPoint = "OpenBackupEventLog")]
```

The EntryPoint property is the source of your problem here.  The exported function names are OpenBackupEventLogA and OpenBackupEventLogW.  Respectively the ANSI and the Unicode versions of this function.  Your declaration would use the ANSI version since you didn't specify the CharSet property.

The pinvoke marshaller can find the A and W versions automatically when ExactSpelling = false (the default).  But not when you specify the name explicitly.

There's no point in using the ANSI version, use CharSet.Auto and omit EntryPoint.  MarshalAs is unnecessary as well, strings already are marshaled as LPTStr.  Thus:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr OpenBackupEventLog(string uncServerName, string fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a 64-bit OS and you are accessing the files using a 32-bit app, the most likely cause of this exception is that the OS very "helpfully" [automatically redirects requests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for the `System` directory (`C:\Windows\system`, e.g.) to the `SysWOW64` directory `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

Fortunately, there is a builtin workaround: the [sysnative](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) directory.

When you generate the path to the file name, use something similar to the following:

string filePath = @"%WINDIR%\sysnative\winevt\logs\mylog.evtx";

However, only do this if you retain the app as a 32-bit app. It will not resolve correctly as a 64-bit app.

Comment: According to the OP's comment, that is not the problem, though I suspected this too...

Answer (score 0):

This was a <strike>encoding</strike> Unicode vs ANSI issue - I seemed to manage to get this to start working again somehow, but later realised that it was returning ANSI strings instead of UNICODE strings - obviously I had accidentally started using the ANSI versions of these functions which is no good.

Its now working with the following PInvoke declaration

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "OpenBackupEventLogW")]
public static extern EventLogHandle OpenBackupEventLog(
    string uncServerName, 
    string fileName);
```

The key points being that I:

- Removed the `MarshalAs` attributes
- Added the `CharSet = CharSet.Unicdoe` paramter to my `DllImport` declaration
- Added W to the end of the entry point name

Note that it also seems to work if I remove the W from the end of the entry point name as long s the `CharSet = CharSet.Unicdoe` paramter is there.